# What is keyComparator in Java?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I was studying Collection and HashMap and came across to keyComparator. I searched on the net but I could not find any tutorial. What is keyComparator and when is used in Java applications?

Answer (score 0):

***edit***

Have you looked at its code to see what it does? Java classes are open source (at least on the oracle website) so its best to check what the code is about there:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/